# Microhelp stops working upon app losing focus

Tags: powerbuilder

With Powerbuilder 10.5 on Windows Vista, I am looping through datawindow rows and putting some text in microhelp for each iteration.

If I click on another app, say outlook as an example, the Microhelp stops updating on the PB App even after Outlook has been closed.  Happens on all apps not just Outlook.

Comment: FWIW, when I moved to Vista (can't say if it was the operating system or the version of PB), I found that any updates to the window weren't getting processed after the app lost focus. IOW, it either stopped receiving paint messages, or it stopped processing them. Even my code to force paint messages to process during long loops stopped working. Never tracked it down. Can only offer empathy.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything relevant in a LoseFocus event somewhere in the call stack?
Check the entire ancestor chain - from the datawindow to its ancestor classes, to window and its ancestor classes, as well as Application.

PBLPeeper is a great app for this kind of research.  www.techno-kitten.com